# Extending a page that extends another in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

welcome.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
@yield('posts')
@endsection
```

posts.blade.php:

```
@extends('welcome')
@section('posts')
asfdsfdsf
@endsection
```

Both files are in the same folder outside of the layouts folder. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of depends what you have in your `app.blade.php`. If you have:

```
@yield('content')
```

then you should have displayed `asfdsfdsf` without any problem.

**EDIT**

Full working example:

In controller:

```
return view('test.posts');
```

resources/views/test/posts.blade.php:

```
@extends('test.welcome')
@section('posts')
    asfdsfdsf
@stop
```

resources/views/test/welcome.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    @yield('posts')
@stop
```

resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php

```
@yield('content')
```

Result is:

```
asfdsfdsf
```

as expected

Comment: I removed every code and just left the @yield('content') and it still won't work

Comment: Oh I get it now. I'm loading the wrong file. Is there any way to get the contents of posts and app into the welcome?

Comment: @DanielSanchez Not really, if you extend them, that you use yield and in child view define sections to tell what should be put into this yield

Answer (score 0):

That should work if you have a template file at /app/resources/views/layout/app.blade.php that contains

```
<p>Some content here</p>

@yield('content')

<p>Some additional content here</p>
```

Then in your /app/resources/views/welcome.blade.php, the content

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<h1> Your name is Daniel </h1>

@stop
```

posts.blade.php:

```
@extends('welcome')

@section('posts')

asfdsfdsf
@stop
```